# Is there a way to a maintain the function signature in C and not in a SQL file?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, c

[Currently the docs says,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/xfunc-c.html#XFUNC-C-RETURN-SET)

> There are two ways you can build a composite data value (henceforth a “tuple”): you can build it from an array of `Datum` values, or from an array of C strings that can be passed to the input conversion functions of the tuple's column data types.

When it comes to returning that "tuple" it says,

> One way to declare this function in SQL is:
>
> ```sql
> CREATE TYPE __retcomposite AS (f1 integer, f2 integer, f3 integer);
>
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retcomposite(integer, integer)
>     RETURNS SETOF __retcomposite
>     AS 'filename', 'retcomposite'
>     LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
> ```
>
> A different way is to use OUT parameters:
>
> ```sql
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retcomposite(IN integer, IN integer,
>    OUT f1 integer, OUT f2 integer, OUT f3 integer)
>    RETURNS SETOF record
>    AS 'filename', 'retcomposite'
>    LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
> ```
>
> Notice that in this method the output type of the function is formally an anonymous record type.

But is there a way to put the contents of `__retcomposite` in C too? It seems kind of sloppy to have to write/maintain the prototype for the function in C, and in another language (SQL).

To expand a bit, [there is a hook when you load the .so into the database with `_PG_init`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42579770/124486). Is there no way to write my function signature there. It seems redundant to have to do something [like this](https://github.com/EvanCarroll/pg-dump-fcinfo/blob/main/src/dump_fcinfo.c#L22) where I tell C what all my types are (the initial defaults) when I then have to tell SQL [the very same thing](https://github.com/EvanCarroll/pg-dump-fcinfo/blob/main/dump_fcinfo--0.0.1.sql#L2).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are talking about.

The “prototype” is only in SQL in the shape of the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.

In C, all functions are declared and defined alike:

```c
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(retcomposite);

Datum
retcomposite(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    [...]
}
```

You could probably use the `PG_init` function in the shared object to run a `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.  Then you'd need to `LOAD` the shared object as superuser to define the function. I don't think that would be an improvement: I don't think that `LOAD 'retcomposite'` is much simpler than `CREATE EXTENSION retcomposite`, and the C code would become much more complicated (check if the function is already there, invoke SPI, ...).

Comment: _"The “prototype” is only in SQL in the shape of the CREATE FUNCTION statement."_ I'm asking if it's possible to put this prototype (declaration of arguments and return types) in C too, so it can live in the same file and I don't have to manually keep them in sync. Is there a method to write the `CREATE FUNCTION` command in C in the `foo` extension and have it load when someone writes `CREATE EXTENSION foo`

Comment: No, that's not possible. How do you propose to create a database object from a definition in C? I had assumed that you are complaining about a perceived redundancy, but it seems that you simply don't agree with the way C functions work in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I expanded in the question